# Overload object operation in Perl

Tags: perl

I want to use overloaded operators in a method which modifies an object. I also want to achieve it without duplicating the code.

To illustrate the problem, I will show a simplified version of what I am trying to do. In my original code, the `add` method overloads `+` and `complicated_calculation` method tries to update the object.

The `add` method creates a new `Number` object to avoid an expression like `$n + 1` modifying the object.

```
package Number;

use overload
    '0+' => 'get_value',
    '+' => 'add';

sub new {
    my ($class, $value) = @_;
    my $self->{value} = $value;
    return bless($self, $class);
}

sub get_value {
    my ($self) = @_;
    return $self->{value};
}

sub set_value {
    my ($self, $value) = @_;
    $self->{value} = $value;
}

# Actual class has more attributes and the logic of addition includes branches.
sub add {
    my ($self, $other) = @_;
    print "add $other\n";
    return Number->new($self->get_value + $other);
}

sub complicated_calculation {
    my ($self) = @_;
    # Do something complicated.
    $self += 10;
}


package main;

my $n = Number->new(1);

print $n + 1 . "\n";

$n++;
print $n . "\n";

$n->complicated_calculation;
print $n . "\n";
```

Will output

```
add 1
2
add 1
2
add 10
2
```

I want the result of `complicated_calculation` method (12) to be printed, but 2 is printed instead. The result of the `complicated_calculation` method is set to an object created by the `add` method, instead of to the object which called it.

I can make the `complicated_calculation` method update the object using an `add_in_place` method to add a number in-place, but this requires duplicated code in `add` and `add_in_place` which I was taught to avoid.

In the actual application the `Number` class will have many more attributes, and the code for addition will be much longer.

```
package Number;

use overload
    '0+' => 'get_value',
    '+' => 'add',
    '+=' => 'add_in_place',
    'fallback' => 1;

sub new {
    my ($class, $value) = @_;
    my $self->{value} = $value;
    return bless($self, $class);
}

sub get_value {
    my ($self) = @_;
    return $self->{value};
}

sub set_value {
    my ($self, $value) = @_;
    $self->{value} = $value;
}

# Actual class has more attributes and the logic of addition includes branches.
sub add {
    my ($self, $other) = @_;
    print "add $other\n";
    return Number->new($self->get_value + $other);
}

sub add_in_place {
    my ($self, $other) = @_;
    print "add_in_place $other\n";
    $self->set_value($self->get_value + $other);
}

sub complicated_calculation {
    my ($self) = @_;
    # Do something complicated.
    $self += 10;
}


package main;

my $n = Number->new(1);

print $n + 1 . "\n";

$n++;
print $n . "\n";

$n->complicated_calculation;
print $n . "\n";
```

Will output

```
add 1
2
add_in_place 1
2
add_in_place 10
12
```

I feel that there should be a better way and would like to have some advice from you guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you *must always* `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of *every* Perl program file you write. This applies especially when you are asking for help with your code, as it is the first line of defence against bugs and really should be your first resort before troubling others.

This is happening because the `add` method is called to implement the `+=` operator, which returns a new `Number` object as a result. That results in the value of `$self` within `complicated_calculation` being changed to refer to the *new* `Number` object that, correctly, has a value of 12. But the original value -- `$n` in the main code -- still points to an object with the value of 2.

To get it to work, you could arrange that `complicated_calculation` *returns* the new object, and the calling code assigns it to `$n`. Just changing that statement to

```
$n = $n->complicated_calculation
```

will get it working.

However, it is a little strange to write stuff like that as a method. The code in the `Number` class should be focused on making the object behave correctly, so all the methods should be operators. If you were writing `complicated_calculation` as a subroutine in the `main` package then you would be fine with

```
$n += 10;
print $n;
```

as the copying of `$n` would then work correctly and transparently. It is only when you are writing a *method* that reassigning `$self` makes no sense, because it then no longer refers to the object the calling code is using.

If you really consider `complicated_calculation` to be an operator, then it should mutate the object in-place rather than relying on `overload` to provide the mechanism. If you changed it to

```
sub complicated_calculation {
  my ($self) = @_;
  $self->{value} += 10;
}
```

then everything would work as it should.

---

**Update**

I strongly believe that you should write everything in terms of `add_in_place`, which should be a private method for use only internally by the class.

Both `add` and `complicated_calculation` can be very simply rewritten, and there is no longer any need to write `$n = $n->complicated_calculation` as the method modifies the object in-place.

This example code for the module demonstrates.

```
package Number;

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use overload
    '0+' => 'get_value',
    '+'  => 'add';

sub new {
  my ($class, $value) = @_;
  bless { value => $value };
}

sub get_value {
  my ($self) = @_;
  $self->{value};
}

sub set_value {
  my ($self, $value) = @_;
  $self->{value} = $value;
}

sub add {
    my ($self, $other) = @_;
    print "add $other\n";
    Number->new($self->get_value)->add_in_place($other);
}

sub add_in_place {
    my ($self, $other) = @_;
    print "add_in_place $other\n";
    $self->{value} += $other;
    $self;
}

sub complicated_calculation {
  my ($self) = @_;
  $self->add_in_place(10);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I had to admit that my question wasn't clear enough.

New `Number` object is created by `add` method. And the reason for that is, I don't want `Number` objected to be updated by `$n + 1`.

I thought copy constructor is autogenerated only for objects based on scalars. But in my case, object is a hash reference.
> Note also that the copy constructor (key '=' ) may be autogenerated, but only for objects based on scalars.

Comment: Also actual class is not as simple as `Number` class. The class has more attributes and the addition will check several attributes and have several `if`s.

Sorry for the confusion. I will update my question.

But thanks for the help.

Comment: @SaigoUeno: I think the documentation for `overload` may be incorrect. Please see the update to my solution.

Comment: `$n = $n->complicated_calculation` did worked. It looks a little strange but not so bad.
I will wait for several days for ideas to come and may be I will choose your idea for my code. Thanks. And I will check your update.

Comment: @SaigoUeno: I've just understood what you mean by *"New Number object is created by `add` method"*. You're correct, the new object isn't being created by a copy constructor but by `add`. I apologise for my mistake. But if you want to keep `complicated_calculation` as a method then you should modify the object in-place as I described, with `$self->{value} += 10`. You shouldn't have to copy the result of a method in the calling code.

Comment: Unfortunately actual `Number` class can't be updated by simple `$self->{value} += 10`. And that's why I want to use overload operation in `complicated_calculation`. Logic of plus has around 50 lines and I don't want to duplicate it in `add` and `add_in_place` and `complicated_calculation` method.
Also, I don't want `Number` object to be updated by `$n + 1`. So we can't update `Number` object in-place in `add` method. Using only `add` method (no `add_in_place` method) and `$n = $n->complicated_calculation` works around the dilemma. What a smart idea!

Comment: @SaigoUeno: The only thing left that puzzles me is *why* a copy constructor is necessary for mutators like `+=`. The basic arithmetic operator `+` *must* create and return a new object anyway, so it makes an additional copy constructor superfluous.

Comment: Updating `Number` object in-place is what `add_in_place` is doing. (The second code in my question.) This works fine, but plus logic is duplicated in `add` and `add_in_place` method which I want to avoid if possible.
I also wanted to know how methods should be written when overloading mathematical operator for objects.

Comment: @SaigoUeno: You may think it smart, but I am very unhappy with it. As I wrote, a method of `Number` should behave as an *operator* and it isn't doing that. There is no need to write anything other than `add_in_place` (which should be an internal method). You can write everything else in terms of that. I have added to my solution to explain.

Comment: I got it. So your point was that method should work on object which called it. I totally agree with you. I need to think some more to get things straight. But I feel that your solution will solve my problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @SaigoUeno: I also think you will find you need a `clone` method so that you can save intermediate `Number` values. If your hash is just a single level with no references as values then it will be as simple as `bless { %$self }`

Comment: Definitely yes. I found `Storable::dclone` for multilevel clone which I know you already know.